# Why am I getting '502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)' on my server ap

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I am running my frontend and backend application on nginx server in digital ocean. It was working very fine. Suddenly, i get the error '502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)' when i try to run the application.

If i run `sudo nginx -t`, I get `nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful`

This is my config file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    rewrite ^/(.*) https+//mydomain.com/$1 permanent;
}


server {
        #listen 80 default_server;
        #listen [::]:80 default_server;


        #listen 80;
        #server_name mydomain.com;
        #rewrite ^/(.*) https+//mydomain.com/$1 permanent;


        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        # SSL configuration
       

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        #server_name _;
        server_name mydomain.com;
        ssl_certificate /home/admin/mydomain.com.chained.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/admin/mydomain.com.key;


location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }


location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

I get the error when i try to access mydomain.com/api

but it works fine with mydomain.com

Help please anyone

UPDATE
I get this error in the logs

```
sudo tail -F /var/log/nginx/error.log

2022/05/03 13:35:31 [error] 791993#791993: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: ***.***.***.***, server: mydomain.com, request: "GET /api HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api", host: "mydomain.com"
```

Comment: this error means that `http://localhost:3000` does not respond to passed requests

Comment: Any Idea on how I can resolve this?

Comment: watch logs of your `localhost:3000` backend, check is it launched first

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new here. whats the command for watching the logs on `localhost:3000`. I launched 2 applications on the server. CLient is working well on the main url but API is not. How can i also check if the server is launched?

Comment: `lsof -i:3000` or `netstat -tnlp | grep :3000`

Comment: Thank you. My application on 3000 is returning a table. but the application on :8000 (which is the one i'm having an issue with), isn't returning anything. How can i fix this??

Comment: it's not `nginx` related question, so please add another thread with proper explanation and details

Comment: I faced the same issue and nothing worked but then I killed the previous port in my case was 8080 started pm2 again and everything worked fine.